# R: Choosing column range dynamically in Functions (specifically several month / years)

Tags: r, function

I have several data.frames (for multiple areas). All of them are having the same structure and column names. Example:

```
'data.frame':   50742 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ theta_0  : num  0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 0.089 ...
 $ theta_1  : num  0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 0.16 ...
 $ theta_2  : num  0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 0.123 ...
 $ theta_A  : num  0.161 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 0.162 ...
 $ theta_B  : num  0.152 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 0.153 ...
 $ theta_C  : num  0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 0.136 ...
 $ timepoint: POSIXct, format: "2021-03-19 01:00:00" "2021-03-19 01:20:00" "2021-03-19 01:40:00" "2021-03-19 02:00:00" ...
 $ year     : chr  "2021" "2021" "2021" "2021" ...
 $ month    : chr  "03" "03" "03" "03" ...
```

**My goal** (already made this happen) is to have a new data.frame with percentages. These percentages show how many of the values are below a certain threshold. This threshold is different for every column and every area (data.frame). I would like to filter these output table to see how percentages differ in certain months and years.

This is how I processed my data:

1. Defining thresholds:

```
thres_B <- boden$Threshold_example[c(1:6)] 
thres_C <- boden$Threshold_example[c(7:12)] 
...
```

2. Functions for receiving percentages:

```
trocken_0 <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_0<thres[1],TRUE,FALSE))}
trocken_1 <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_1<thres[2],TRUE,FALSE))}
trocken_2 <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_2<thres[3],TRUE,FALSE))}
trocken_A <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_A<thres[4],TRUE,FALSE))}
trocken_B <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_B<thres[5],TRUE,FALSE))}
trocken_C <- function(datas, thres) {mean(ifelse(datas$theta_C<thres[6],TRUE,FALSE))}
```

3. Merge all values in one table (for one area/ dataframe):

```
tabelle <- function (datas, thres) {
  
 data.frame(theta_0=trocken_0(datas, thres),
            theta_1=trocken_1(datas, thres),
            theta_2=trocken_2(datas, thres),
            theta_A=trocken_A(datas, thres),
            theta_B=trocken_B(datas, thres),
            theta_C=trocken_C(datas, thres),
            Data=deparse(substitute(datas))
            )
}
```

4. Merge new dataframes of all areas:

```
df_list <- list(
  
  B_perc <- tabelle(B_moist, thres_B),
  C_perc <- tabelle(C_moist, thres_C),
  D_perc <- tabelle(D_moist, thres_D),
  E_perc <- tabelle(E_moist, thres_E), 
  FO_perc <- tabelle(FO_moist, thres_FO),
  FU_perc <- tabelle(FU_moist, thres_FU),
  G_perc <- tabelle(G_moist, thres_G),
  HO_perc <- tabelle(HO_moist, thres_HO),
  HU_perc <- tabelle(HU_moist, thres_HU),
  I_perc <- tabelle(I_moist, thres_I),
  JO_perc <- tabelle(JO_moist, thres_JO),
  K_perc <- tabelle(K_moist, thres_K),
  U_perc <- tabelle(U_moist, thres_U),
  V_perc <- tabelle(V_moist, thres_V),
  X_perc <- tabelle(X_moist, thres_X),
  Y_perc <- tabelle(Y_moist, thres_Y),
  Z_perc <- tabelle(Z_moist, thres_Z))
                
finallist <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list)
```

As you can see, this final table covers all values. With my procedure above, I have issues filtern. If I would like to receive the percentages for all months of 2021 separately, I would have to subset all data.frames into different months and then implement them individually into 4). This would take a very long time:

```
SubsetMarch2021B <- subset(B_moist, B_moist$year == "2021" & B_moist$month == "03")

SubsetMarch2021C <- subset(C_moist, C_moist$year == "2021" & C_moist$month == "03")

...
```

```
df_list <- list(

B_perc_0321 <- tabelle(SubsetMarch2021B, thres_B),
C_perc_0321 <- tabelle(SubsetMarch2021C, thres_C),
...)
                
finallist_March21 <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), df_list)
```

Same for all other month...